# Will older Dell rails work on the newer 11G servers?

Tags: dell-poweredge, rackmount

We have a Dell Poweredge 1950 that came with Dell Rapid Rails. These are the tool-less mounting rails for 4 post square hole racks.

We have some new Dell Poweredge R610s on the way. We were hoping to use the existing 1950 rails but it looks like Dell has a new type of rail for the 11G Poweredge series (yay) called the Ready Rail:
http://www.server-racks.com/11g-ready-rails.html

Does anyone know from first hand experience if the old Dell Rapid Rails work with the newer 11G servers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not compatible. I'm pretty sure the standoffs on the side of the new server won't match with the slots on the old rails, and the new servers use a latching mechanism instead of the thumbscrews to hold the server in place in the rack.

Comment: Yup different rails.